# помогите найти ошибку hook useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Пытаюсь вникнуть в хуки и переписываю этот класс.Этот класс получает от класса выше пропсы getData - fetch запрос к API, itemId - айдишник в списке, по которому кликнул пользователь, по дефолту приходит null и филды

```
const Field = ({item, field, label}) => {
    return (
        <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span className="term">{label}</span>
            <span>{item[field]}</span>
       </li>
    )
}
```

которые рендерят содержимое.

```
export default class ItemDetails extends Component {

    state = {
        item: null,
        loading: true,
        error: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateItem();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.itemId !== prevProps.itemId) {
            this.updateItem();
        }
    }

    onItemDetailsLoaded = (item) => {
        this.setState({
            item,
            loading: false
        })
    }

    updateItem() {
        const {itemId} = this.props;
        if (!itemId) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })

        this.props.getData(itemId)
            .then( this.onItemDetailsLoaded )
            .catch( () => this.onError())
    }

    onError(){
        this.setState({
            item: null,
            error: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        
        if (!this.state.item && this.state.error) {
            return <ErrorMessage/>
        } else if (!this.state.item) {
            return <span className="select-error">Please select a character</span>
        }

        const {item} = this.state;
        const {name} = item;
        

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <div className="char-details rounded">
                    <Spinner/>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="char-details rounded">
                <h4>{name}</h4>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {
                        React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
                            return (React.cloneElement(child, {item}))
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Получилось следующее

```
function ItemDetails(props) {

    
    const [item, itemUpdate] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.itemId) {
            return;
        }
        props.getData(props.itemId)
        .then(data => {
            itemUpdate(data);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [])

   
    console.log(props.itemId);
        
   if (!item) {
        return <span className="select-error">Please select a character</span>
    }

  
    const {name} = item;

    return (
        <div className="char-details rounded">
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                {
                    React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
                        return (React.cloneElement(child, {item}))
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что на классах все работало и рендерилось. Сейчас же, если я захардкодил itemId, то он отображает то, что нужно мне. Если я передаю в fetch itemId через пропсы, то ничего не рендерится. Сам itemId приходит, через консоль я его вывожу, но почему-то ничего не работает. Если в useEffect я убираю [] как второй аргумент, то все рабоатет, но идут утечки информации. Гуглил что нужны квадратные скобки чтобы их убрать, но тогда все перестает работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй аргумент в `useEffect` (да и в большинстве хуков, про все не могу ручаться) это зависимости. Хук следит за зависимостями и "дёргается" только в том случае, если значение поменялось.

```
   useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.itemId) {
            return;
        }
        props.getData(props.itemId)
        .then(data => {
            itemUpdate(data);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }, [props.itemId]) // обновить только если itemId поменялся
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. т.е. в моем случае хук просто не "дергался" потому-что он не следил за пропсом, который я передаю ему? нужно перечитать эту тему внимательнее )